# Minimum XOR problem, exceeds the time limit and gives different answers in few cases

Tags: c++, arrays, c, data-structures, time-complexity

I am trying to solve the **Minimum AND xor OR** problem ([here](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/minimum-and-xor-or-3fa51940/)) from the hacker rank, it runs well in the sample case but in the 1st input case scenario where the number of test case(T) is 1000 it provides 20 **wrong answers**
**Ex.: The input array of 10 numbers [853, 864, 10, 547, 954, 235, 822, 429, 628, 569] gives the result 53 while the correct ans is 26.**                                                      (rest 980 are correct), and in **rest of the input case scenario the time limits exceeds.**
I tried to debug but am hitting the dead-end.
Is there any way to make it more feasible, apart from using different sorting method(like `qsort`) ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int arr[100000];
int cal[1000000];

int arrinp(int arr[], int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
}

void sort(int arr[], int N)
{
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int arrcal(int arr[], int cal[], int N)
{
    sort(arr, N);
    int ans1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        cal[i] = arr[i] ^ arr[i + 1];
    }
    sort(cal, N);
}

int main()
{
    int T, N, temp;
    scanf("%d ", &T);
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ", &N);
        arrinp(arr, N);
        sort(arr, N);
        arrcal(arr, cal, N);
        sort(cal, N);
        printf("%d\n", cal[0]);
    }
}
```

**NEW SOLUTION**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int arr[100000];
int cal[1000000];

int arrinp(int arr[], int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
}

int compareInt(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    const int *p1 = pa;
    const int *p2 = pb;
    return *p1 - *p2;
}


int arrcal(int arr[], int cal[], int N)
{
    int ans1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        cal[i] = arr[i] ^ arr[i + 1];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int T, N, temp;
    scanf("%d ", &T);
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ", &N);
        arrinp(arr, N);
        qsort(arr, N, sizeof(int), compareInt);
        arrcal(arr, cal, N);
        qsort(cal, N - 1, sizeof(int), compareInt);
        printf("%d\n", cal[0]);
    }
}
```

Thanks all for your help, the `qsort` resolved both the issues.
P.S.: Anyone can explain why the `qsort` gave the correct ans in the above example (of 10 elements) whereas the function `sort()` failed?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am doing it to build my logic.And I think many competitive coders end up in FAANG companies. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think your sort function is not entirely correct, but as bubblesort is not the right choice for 1e5 size data anyway, I would suggest not debugging it, toss it out and ... use the `qsort` one that ships with the language.

Comment: Wikipedia on competitive programming: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_programming#Benefits_and_criticism

Comment: @molbdnilo it's not at all obvious, but it seems to be correct. `&^|` collapses into plain xor and the minimal pairs are indeed likely to be next to each other if you sort the numbers. It takes some reasoning (not sure if OP actually did that...). I think the real problem is that sort is ignoring the last element and that it is bubblesort in the first place...

Comment: You can ignore πάντα ῥεῖ’s comments. They are opinions stated without basis and in ways that are somewhat inappropriate in presentation and substance. That said, exercises of this sort generally do not appear to be tutorial, in that they are not teaching concepts. Solving them may require using various concepts, so they may be opportunities for exercising things you learn elsewhere or demonstrating things you learn elsewhere. But actually learning the concepts in the first place generally requires study from textbooks or other sources.

Comment: In particular, problems such as this one are not feasible to solve merely by writing code to evaluate the stated properties. They are designed to require deeper concepts. Exceed a time limit is an indication of that—there is a solution that avoids the “try all possibilities” approach. You need to approach them by thinking about how the problem can be divided or reorganized into something requiring less computation. Knowledge of that is hard to develop by oneself—various concepts involved in these problems took humans collectively decades or more to develop…

Comment: … So you need to read what other people have written, since that can give you the same knowledge in weeks, months, or years (depending on which concepts) instead of decades or longer.

Comment: Note that the second `sort` is overskill as you only need to get the munimum value in the array. Basically, your strategy seems quite correct, just use `qsort` as already mentioned. At leat correct your bubble sort (`j < n`).

Comment: This takes us to the votes to close the problem, which I disagree with. There is some propensity on Stack Overflow to help people with simple coding exercises—show us your code, and we will debug it—and to reject more abstract problems. But simple coding exercises are not of high value and are better learned by working through textbooks, courses, and resources involving fewer people (teachers, teaching assistants, classmates) before expending the attention of many people. Abstract concepts have more value and should be encouraged on Stack Overflow more than they are.

Comment: If the competitive programming exercise itself has limited value because it is not tutorial, then asking about it on Stack Overflow is an opportunity to provide the missing value, by providing explanation and discussion of valuable concepts. So closing the question is a bad decision.

Comment: @Eric in my understanding, OP already got the good concept. I have voted to reopen too. OP clearly is not far to solve a not so easy problem.

Comment: @Damien: I think you are write; their `arrcal` looks like it incorporates the ideas I discussed, so I am deleting those comments. So the actual cause of the time limit exceed would be the sort.

Comment: Regarding the edit: As has been pointed out, your `sort` is both broken (the bound on `j` is wrong) and slow (it is O(n^2), but a sort ought to be O(n log n)). Either change it to use `qsort` or write an O(n log n) sort instead of a bubble sort. Also, you only need to sort the inputs. Then you can scan the array for the minimum XOR without saving all of the XOR results.

Comment: "don't roll your own, use the library one" is an industry best practice. Knowing your way around the standard library and what it already provides for you is an important skill too (which is why I suggested qsort). And there is no way around the fact that an O(N^2) algorithm like bubble sort is too slow for data of this size, so you have to use a different algorithm in any case.

Comment: @dratenik Thanks, it resolved both the problems, time complexity & the answers.

Comment: @Damien done, used qsort and it resolved time complexity & the answers. Thanks for you help :D

Comment: @EricPostpischil Read your every comment, thanks for your help, the ```qsort``` resolved  time complexity problems & gave the correct answers

Comment: "Anyone can explain why..." we did. The for loop bound `j < N - 1` should be `j<N`, otherwise you're skipping the last element and leaving it in place. Which can be seen with your sample sequence, just call your sort on it and print the result.

Comment: @dratenik, Yup, I got it now, thanks for pointing it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both problems, the erroneous results and the time limit exceeded, appear to be caused by this routine:

```
void sort(int arr[], int N)
{
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The bound on `j`, `j < N - 1`, is incorrect as it means the last element of the array is never examined. It ought to be `j < N`.

Even with that fixed, this is an O(*N*<sup>2</sup>) sort. It takes too long. Good [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) are O(*N* log *N*). The `qsort` routine in the standard C library provides an efficient algorithm:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

static int CompareInt(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    // Convert "void *" pointers to "int *" and use them to get the int values.
    int a = * (const int *) pa, b = * (const int *) pb;
    if      (a < b)  return -1;
    else if (a == b) return  0;
    else             return +1;
}

void sort(int arr[], int N)
{
    qsort(arr, N, sizeof *arr, CompareInt);
}
```

Additionally, sorting `cal` is unnecessary. The array can be scanned for its minimum value without sorting it.